# Исчезают переносы строк при переходе в Gmail через Intent на Samsung

Tags: java, android, samsung

Использую intent для перехода из приложения на почту и заполнение письма шаблоном.

```
 `public class BasicHelper {
        public static Intent reportQuestion(Long id, String text, String explanation) {

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(

                    "mailto","gmail@test.com", null));

            String subject  = "Subject #" + id;
            String questionBody = Html.fromHtml(String.format(Locale.US, "<br><br> <b>Question</b>: <br> %s <br><br> <b>Explanation:</b><br>%s",
                    text,
                    explanation

            ).toString();


            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, questionBody);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, questionBody);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:receipient@mail.com?subject="+subject+"&body="+questionBody);
            emailIntent.setData(uri);

            return emailIntent;
        }
    }`
```

При переходе на почту на нормальных устройствах ошибок не возникает, все работает волшебно, однако при переходе на почту на Samsung стираются все переносы строк и в questionBody в письме сплошной текст, подскажите пожалуйста почему может возникать данная проблема и в какую сторону смотреть чтобы исправить;

Comment: Вот тот кто поставил минус, можно пожалуйста узнать почему это было сделано?

Comment: Я поставил минус. За то, что заголовок не связан с проблемой.

Comment: Но ведь проблема возникает в  результате того что указано в заголовке

Comment: Вы не знаете в результате чего возникает проблема. То, что она возникает в такой ситуации, не означает, что она возникает в результате этого. Плюс, ваша проблема в том, что исчезают переносы строк, а не в том как перейти в гмэйл на самсунге.

Comment: @ДанилСычев, вы точно говорите про `subject`? У вас в коде в нём нет переносов строк. Покажите тот текст, который у вас ломается. Возможно надо иначе переносы строк сделать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, извиняюсь, неправильно написал ошибка не в Subject а в самом письме, т.е. String questionBody, переносы там заданы с помощью тегов <br><br>, однако при открытии письма в Gmail они пропадают, и эта проблема возникает именно при переходе в Gmail, в другом почтовом сервисе на самсунг её нет, она стабильно воспроизводится на разных реальных девайсах самсунг

Comment: Кстати, о багах. Есть организации, где в баг-трекерах запрещено использовать слова "баг", "проблема" итд, и за них дают по шапке. И так ясно, что баг. Нужно писать какой именно. Т.е. в данном случае, например, "исчезают переносы строк при и далее по тексту".

Comment: @Эникейщик, буду знать, спасибо за совет)
P.S. все претензии ко мне по делу, всё отредактировано

Comment: @ДанилСычев, попробуйте убрать `Html.fromHtml()`, оставив только собственно текст.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, это к сожалению не помогло

Comment: @ДанилСычев, видел в сети предложения заменить `br` тэги на переносы строк вида `\n` 
или `\r\n` или `\r`

Comment: пробовал это, к сожалению это не помогает, проблема не в том,чтобы задать переносы, я их задавал и таким способом тоже, однако при передаче его уже внутри Intent переносы удаляются почему-то

Comment: Да и кстати, покажите как выглядит контент текстовой строчки `questionBody` то что высылается `Intent`'ом - вдруг там html у вас какой-то кривой :)

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar, text и explanation которые используются для формирования questionBody это два обычных объекта String, т.е. например "Some random text", там не используюется никаких тэгов и тому подобного

Comment: Вот я и говорю, покажите полный `questionBody` - засуньте его в логгер и выложите в сам вопрос... Я вот не очень понимаю, что делает `fromHtml()`

Comment: Автор, так чем дело-то кончилось?

Answer (score 4):

Вы не говорите обработчику `Intent` какой `mime` тип сообщения он обрабатывает.

Я бы предложил вставить:

```
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: Как вариант, в вашем клиенте Gmail вырублено форматирование `html` и по умолчанию стоит *plain text*? Я тоже сижу на Samsung'е и аналогичные `sendto` у меня отлично форматируются.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за совет, но на эмуляторе Genymotion с девайсом Samsung S8 переносы не работают, в том числе и на реальном Samsung S6

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, вы не применяете теги разделения для вашей переменной `text`:

```
String questionBody = Html.fromHtml(String.format(
            Locale.US, 
            "<br/> <b>Question</b>: <br/> %s <br/> <b>Explanation:</b> <br/> %s",
            "<p/> " + text + "<p/>",
            explanation)).toString();
```

Comment: Извините, что долго не отвечал, не было возможности протестировать с компьютера, к сожалению это не помогло